# Chrome developer tools inspector not showing extension stylesheets, even though they're being applied

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

In an extension's manifest file, I have:

```
  "css": ["mycss.css"],
```

In mycss.css, I have:

```
body {
    color: red;
}
```

On a page where the extension runs, **I can see the red being applied**. However inspecting an element does not show 'color' as coming from the extension. I only see, for any element, the pages own CSS.

If I disable the extension, the red goes away. So AFAICT I'm not insane.

How can I make Chrome accurately show where the style is coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome bug: http://crbug.com/132425

This should be fixed in Chrome 22 (http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/120600).

Comment: Thanks so much for answering this - I thought I'd sone something wrong and it was causing such a headache!